# Blogger API into a Google Apps Script AuthO

Tags: google-apps-script

These questions are fast for answering (yes or no)
I am hoping to "delete" and "re-write" some posts of MY blog in blogger, using a Trigger in my Google Apps Script of my Drive (the trigger get data from one of MY SpreadSheets in my Drive).
The question is... do i need to use Auth credentials in MY script in MY Drive or credentials are only when you are in Another "place".. like a webpage or your own server.. ? I am talking about my OWN Script in Drive and my OWN blog in blogger.

What kind of credentials, in my case?

It is very confusing, i was trying doing it with the examples i found here in stackoverflow... but I think they are talking about doing it in whatever webpage

Thanks a lot. Sorry for my bad english a handful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script provide built-in services called **[Google Apps Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/)** and **[Advanced Google Apps Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)** that lets you interact with some Google APIs and Apps Script handles the authorization flow automatically. **In the case of Blogger there is not a built-in service** so you will need to create an authenticated connection.

Take a look at this post [Setting up OAuth2 access with Google Apps Script: Blogger API Example](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/10/setting-up-oauth2-access-with-google-apps-script-blogger-api-example/)